# Disable USB Wifi adapter?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb

I have an old desktop computer running Windows 7 that is connected to the internet with a lan cable. The computer does not have built in Wifi/wireless connection capability. So I bought online one of those small USB Wifi adapter to add wireless capability to it

However, since my computer is getting internet via the lan cable, it is not using the Wifi adapter, even tho its on and searching for wireless networks all the time.

So my question is, should I disable the Wifi adapter in the network devices when im not using it, to prevent early wear of it or something? and only enable it if I need a wireless connection? or it doesnt matter?

thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the OS (Windows 10?).  Please shorten the question, correct capitalization, and remove extra info, which make the question harder to read.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I edited my question following your advices

Comment: Your wireless adapter will not "wear out" if it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 ) Unless you are in a very hot environment or your power company gives unstable power, leaving the USB wifi adapter in won't wear it down.  However, if it's possible to knock it with a leg or crack it into a wall, it's slightly more likely to be broken while plugged in, or break the port it's plugged into.  Small possibility, small problem if it does happen.

2 ) If you have no wireless networks right now, best thing to do is probably put away the adapter, or unplug it and tape it to the side of the PC.  It's a small security danger and it's not doing any good.

3 ) If you ever do connect to a wireless network and still have Ethernet active, Google for "network connection priority" to ensure the one you want is being used.  Ethernet is faster and more secure.